# Sub-spaces, Vector Spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assuming that the sum of U, W is a direct sum. and also U and W are sub-spaces of Vector space V.

Given: If $ x \in U \oplus W$ , $x \notin U$ then $x \in W$ isn't necessary true, which means it may be $x \notin W$

I thought that if $U = R^2$, and $W = \{(0)\}$ and $x = \{(1,1)\}$

then I can say that $ x \notin W$ Thus $x \notin W$

But it seems wrong. Can anyone give me an example of 2 sub-spaces that their sum is a direct sum and if I take a vector that is in their direct sum and not in one of their sub-spaces then that vector is also not in the second sub-space? Very appreciated in advance, thx!

Comment: Let $U=\{(a,0)|a\in \mathbb{R}\}, W=\{(0,b)|b\in \mathbb{R}\}$.  If $x=(1,1)$,.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(1,1)\in\langle\;(1,0)\;\rangle\oplus\langle\;(0,1)\;\rangle$$

yet $\;(1,1)\;$ isn't contained in either of two subspaces above.

Comment: ידעת שאני ישראלי בגלל השם פרטי שלי? ואתה בטח יודע שאני גם לודמ עכשיו לאלגברה לינארית וזה לא כיף חח

Comment: כן, בגלל השם...ואני מניח שאתה לא לומד מתמטיקה כי אלגברה לינארית זה באמת כיף...עם חסרון אחד גדול: יש הרבה עבודה שחורה חישובית

Comment: אפיק מעבר באו"פ לטכניון של מדעי המחשב.

Comment: כן...אנשי מחשבים מזיעים הרבה עם דברים כאלה. בהצלחה