# Linear Algebra - Addition of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question reads:

Let $U, W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Define their sum $U + W$ as

$$U + W = \{u + w : u \in U, w \in W \}$$

Prove: $U + W$ is a subspace of $V$ .

I'm currently not too sure how to approach this question, would I just try to prove closure under addition and multiplication? Any help/ pointers would be appreciated.$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sub-spaces, Vector Spaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808769/sub-spaces-vector-spaces)

Comment: @Jneven I cannot see how this question is a duplicate of your linked on. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there is a $y$ in $U+W$ such that it’s not a member  we of $V$. This means that $y$ is a member of $U$ or a member of $W$ by definition. $y$ cannot be in $U$ since $U$ is a subset (sub space) of $V$ and similar reasoning holds for $W$. So $y$ is a member of $v$. And $U+V$ is at least a subset of $V$.

Now let’s show that the zero vector is in $U+W$:

$U$ is a sub space and therefore contains the zero vector. Then $U+W$ contains $U$ so it must contain the zero vector.

Now let’s prove closure:

If $y$ is in $U+W$ then $ay$ is in $U+W$ for any element of the field. This is because $y$ is either in $U$ or $W$ and those sub spaces have to contain the scale multiples of $y$ to be considered subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that by [**definition of subspace**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace), we need to check that

- $\vec 0 \in U+V$
- $\forall a,b \in \mathbb F,\quad \forall \vec v_1$, $\vec v_2\in U+V \implies a\vec v_1+b\vec v_2\in U+V$